# C# IO.EXCEPTION cannot access file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, io

Im using c# on VS 2012.

I have an explained issue which happens whenever i get Callback from some server.
Im using `Request.SaveAs(filename, true);`

`filename` is actually the the name of the sender(which is get from the Request)+ `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks`.
So far so good, file is usually created.

I have issues that sometimes i get 
IO.EXCEPTION  process cannot access the file

Now, i assume it happens due to transaction delay and it tries to create a file when the streamWriter is still writing the previous request.

First, am I right?

Second, is there any solution for this? like insert it to some queue or any other way?

Thanks.

Comment: I would try to debug this, ex put an entry with the theoretical file name into a separate text file and see if you get duplicates. If yes, then you know you are trying to write to the same file from multiple processes.

Comment: No, you'd get IOException.Message that will talk about a "sharing violation".  "Access denied" is a much more serious mishap.  You'd get that if your program just doesn't have write access to the directory.  Or you are trying to create a file that has the same name as a directory in the same folder.

Comment: ok..so any suggested solutions?